# boost python can't access ios private item

Tags: c++, fstream, boost-python

I have the following code:

```
//test.cpp
#include <Physical_file.h>
#include <boost\python.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;
using namespace FMS_Physical;


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(python_bridge)
{
    class_<Physical_file>("pf")
        .def("pcreate", &Physical_file::pcreate)
    ;
}

//physical_file.h
#include <fstream>
#include "tools.h"
using namespace std;

#define FMS_lvl0_DLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 

namespace FMS_Physical
{
    const int BLOCK_OFFSET = 20 + 4;
    const string SUFFIX(".hash");

    struct block
    {
        unsigned int BlockNr;
        char filler[20];
        char data[1024 - BLOCK_OFFSET];
    };

    class Physical_file
    {
    public:
        fstream filefl;
        string workingDir;
        string fileName;
        int fileSize;
        block currBlock;
        block FHBuffer;
        bool opened;
        string openMode;

        /************
        functions
        ************/

        FMS_lvl0_DLL_API Physical_file(void);
        FMS_lvl0_DLL_API Physical_file(string &FileName, int FileSize, string &Dir = getCurrentPath());
        FMS_lvl0_DLL_API Physical_file(string &FileName, string &Type, string &Dir = getCurrentPath());

        FMS_lvl0_DLL_API ~Physical_file(void);

        void FMS_lvl0_DLL_API pcreate(string &Name, int Size = 1000, string &Dir = getCurrentPath());
        void FMS_lvl0_DLL_API pdelete(void);
        void FMS_lvl0_DLL_API popen(string &name, string &OpenMode = string("I"), string &Dir = getCurrentPath());
        void FMS_lvl0_DLL_API pclose(void);

        void FMS_lvl0_DLL_API seekToBlock(unsigned int BlockNr);

        void FMS_lvl0_DLL_API WriteBlock(void);
        void FMS_lvl0_DLL_API ReadBlock(void);
        void FMS_lvl0_DLL_API WriteFH(void);
        void FMS_lvl0_DLL_API ReadFH(void);

    };
}

//physical_file.cpp
void Physical_file::pcreate(string &Name, int Size, string &Dir)
{
    if (Dir.compare("") == 0)
        Dir = getCurrentPath();
    string fileFullName = Dir + '\\' + Name + SUFFIX;
    this->filefl.open(fileFullName.c_str(),ios::in | ios::binary);
    if (filefl.is_open())
    {
        throw new exception((string("in function Physical_file::pcreate, file:") + fileFullName + " exists.").c_str());
    }
    try{
        this->filefl.open(fileFullName.c_str(),ios::binary | ios::out);
        this->opened = true;
        this->seekToBlock(0);
        this->currBlock.BlockNr = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(currBlock.data); j++)
                this->currBlock.data[j] = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(currBlock.filler); j++)
                this->currBlock.filler[j] = 0;
            this->WriteBlock();
        }

        this->pclose();

        this->fileName = Name;
        this->workingDir = Dir;
        this->fileSize = Size;
    }
    catch(exception e)
    {
        throw new exception("in Physical_file::pcreate \n" + *e.what());
    }
}
Physical_file::Physical_file(void)
{
    this->fileName = string("");
    this->workingDir = string("");
    this->opened = false;
}
```

(there is some more code, I think its irrelevant to the problem)

when trying to compile I get the following error:

```
error C2248: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>'
```

can anyone explain why this problem happens and how to fix it?

(I'm compiling using vs2010, python27 and the c++ boost libs)

the files physical_file.cpp and physical_file.h are compiled to a dll used by test.cpp

Comment: Please don't use `std::string("")`. Just use `std::string()`. Default constructor is much more efficient than initializing from even an empty literal (at least on GCC/libstdc++).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Boost.Python will automatically register `to_python` conversions for exposed types, such as `Physical_file`.  As such, Boost.Python requires that these types be copyable.  In this case, `Physical_file` is not copyable its `filefl` members is of a type that is not copyable: `fstream`.

To resolve this, either:

- Determine copy/ownership semantics of `filefl`, and manage it through a holder object.  For example, [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm).
- Suppress automatic registration of python conversions by providing `boost::noncopyable` as a template argument when exposing the `Physical_file` class.

  ```cpp
  BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(python_bridge)
  {
    boost::python::class_<Physical_file, boost::noncopyable>("pf")
      .def("pcreate", &Physical_file::pcreate)
      ;
  }
  ```

For more options when exposing a C++ class to Python, refer to the [`boost::python::class_`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/python/doc/v2/class.html#class_-spec) documentation.

Comment: I tried the second solution, and the code compiled. Importing the dll in python also works fine, but `pf` is not defined. Any idea's?

Comment: Verify that the library name matches the module name provided to `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE`.  Also, verify that the `import` is loading the module you expect (name clashes, not in `PYTHONPATH`, etc.).  The [-vv](http://docs.python.org/3.1/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-trace-v) option may help provide better insight into what is being loaded.